# c# how do i check if datasource is null?

Tags: c#, data-binding

i have a control on a winform called chart1.

i would like to know whether `chart1.DataSource` is empty

how do i check it?

Comment: How do you check it from where? The obvious answer seems to be `if(chart1.DataSource == null) {}` ... Or do you mean something else by 'empty'?

Comment: What do you mean by empty? Empty as in no data source, or empty as int the tables have no rows (if your data source contains tables for example).

Comment: @JL i need to know if it returned any rows

Comment: chart1.DataSource == null || chart1.DataSource.Count == 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the DataSource is a **DataTable**, you can check first that the DataTable is not null, and secondly that its Rows.Count > 0.

If the DataSource is a **DataSet,** you check for null, then tables, then rows.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if it is null.

```
if(chart1.DataSource == null)
{
 // Do something
}
```

If you know what the DataSource is, then you can cast it and check to see if it is empty or not. For example:

```
List<String> strings = new List<String>() { "a", "b" };

// Set chart1.DataSource to strings... then later on
if(chart1.DataSource != null)
{
   List<String> boundStrings = chart1.DataSource as List<String>;
   if(boundStrings != null && boundStrings.Count > 0)
   {
      // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: sorry i need to know if it has 0 rows

Comment: see the updated answer... it depends on what your DataSource is though as to what you need to cast to.

Answer (score 2):

personally id check the datasource for null BEFORE I bind it to chart so I don't have to worry about chart1 dealing with a null datasource

Answer (score 1):

```
if (chart1.DataSource == null)
{
    // The DataSource is empty
}
```